# Using Interrupts to keep the servo running for a set time

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

My goal is to press a button on the controller to activate the servo for 1 minute. I want the servo to go from 0 to 20 in increments of 1. Upon pressing the button on the controller, I want this cycle for the servo to repeat for 1 minute. This is the code I have so far. But for right now  this makes the servo move as long as the button remains pressed.

```
This makes the servo move as long as the button remains pressed, but I am trying to have the servo activate and run for a minute once the button is pressed
*******************************************/
#include <IRremote.h>      
#include <Servo.h>
#include <TimerOne.h>

#define interruptNumber 0 
#define RECV_PIN 2      
#define button1 0xFF30CF 
#define servoPin 10 

Servo myservo;  
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

volatile byte IREventFlag;


void setup()
{
  pinMode(RECV_PIN, INPUT);//define the interrupt pin as an input
  Timer1.initialize(100); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(InterruptServiceRoutine);
}
 
void loop(){
  if (IREventFlag==1){
    servo_move();
    IREventFlag=0;//reset the flag for the next interrupt
  }
}

void InterruptServiceRoutine(){
  if(digitalRead(RECV_PIN)==HIGH)   //when button is not pressed the output is HIGH
  {
    digitalWrite(servoPin, LOW);            
  }
  if(digitalRead(RECV_PIN)==LOW)    //presseing button causes output to go LOW
  {
    digitalWrite(servoPin, HIGH);
    IREventFlag=1;//set the flag to tell the main loop that a touch event occurred.
  }
}

//runs servo for 1 min and goes between 0 and 20 deg in increments of 1
void servo_move(){ 
    for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){
        myservo.write(i);
        delay(10);
        }
    for(int i = 20; i>0; i--){
      myservo.write(i);
      delay(10);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the addition of some boolean variable, we can make sure to only call the 'servo_move' function on a rising edge button press (when the button was previously in an unpressed state and is then pressed).

```
This makes the servo move as long as the button remains pressed, but I am trying to have the servo activate and run for a minute once the button is pressed
*******************************************/
#include <IRremote.h>      
#include <Servo.h>
#include <TimerOne.h>

#define interruptNumber 0 
#define RECV_PIN 2      
#define button1 0xFF30CF 
#define servoPin 10 

Servo myservo;  
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

volatile byte IREventFlag;
bool risingEdgeDetection = True;


void setup()
{
  pinMode(RECV_PIN, INPUT);//define the interrupt pin as an input
  Timer1.initialize(100); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(InterruptServiceRoutine);
}
 
void loop(){
  if (IREventFlag==1 && risingEdgeDetection == True){
    servo_move();
    IREventFlag=0;//reset the flag for the next interrupt
    risingEdgeDetection = False;
  }
}

void InterruptServiceRoutine(){
  if(digitalRead(RECV_PIN)==HIGH)   //when button is not pressed the output is HIGH
  {
    risingEdgeDetection = True;
    digitalWrite(servoPin, LOW);            
  }
  if(digitalRead(RECV_PIN)==LOW)    //presseing button causes output to go LOW
  {
    digitalWrite(servoPin, HIGH);
    IREventFlag=1;//set the flag to tell the main loop that a touch event occurred.
  }
}

//runs servo for 1 min and goes between 0 and 20 deg in increments of 1
void servo_move(){ 
    for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){
        myservo.write(i);
        delay(10);
        }
    for(int i = 20; i>0; i--){
      myservo.write(i);
      delay(10);
}}
```

Comment: I uploaded the changes, but it still wont run the servo for a minute after pressing the button.

Comment: Sorry, with your current code you will have to modify the delay input to be 1500 (1.5s) to make it run the servo for a full minute.